# NSLog with CGPoint data

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, nslog

I have a CGPoint called point that is being assigned a touch:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
```

I want to get the x coordinate value into my console log:

```
NSLog(@"x: %s", point.x);
```

When I use this, log output for this is:

x: (null)

I have verified that point is not null when this is called using the debugger and variable watch.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks // :)

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Actually, the real easiest way to log a `CGPoint` is:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
```

The desktop Cocoa equivalent is `NSStringFromPoint()`.

Comment: This is even better. The first answer is the easiest and lightest weight way. But this gets me both x and y from the CGPoint in one set. Nice :) Great tool :)

Comment: Since StackOverflow saw fit to reintroduce this question in my RSS feed, I may as well pimp my general solution: http://jens.ayton.se/blag/almost-elegant-cave-man-debugging/ which allows you to go `JA_DUMP(point);` and get “point = { 43, 96 }” logged without having to worry about format codes.

Comment: How do I use your lib since it compiles on I386 but not on ARM? I mean, how can I work on iOS projects using it?

Comment: First, you’d need to build the FindAlignment.c file as an iOS app and run it on a device (not simulator). Then, copy the result into a new #elif block before the #else at line 172 in JAValueToString.m. If this doesn’t work, additional debugging will be required. I can’t do it since I’m not in the iOS programme.

Comment: Also worth noting that NSStringFromCGRect() exists too.

Comment: you can this helper to keep code clean 
#define CGLog(a) NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(a))

Answer (score 24):

point.x is a floating point number, so you should use:

```
NSLog(@"x: %f", point.x);
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to log a `CGPoint` value is to use the `NSValue` class, since it will give you all the relevant values formatted nicely for the console. It's done like so:

```
NSLog(@"myPoint = %@", [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myPoint]);
```

You can also use the `+valueWithCGRect` and `+valueWithCGSize` methods of `NSValue` when you're trying to log, say, the `frame` (`CGRect`) or `size` (`CGSize`) properties of a `UIView`.

Answer (score 2):

`NSLog(@"point x,y: %f,%f", point.x, point.y);`

Answer (score 0):

`point.x` is a floating point number
 so you should code like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%f",point.x]);
```

Comment: If u want to String value means u just use this!!

Comment: You're doing an unnecessary format string within a format string.  Philippe's and Ahruman's approaches are much simpler and they achieve the exact same results.

Answer (score 0):

use :

> NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));

You can also use NSString for following info :

> NSStringFromCGPoint
>       NSStringFromCGSize
>       NSStringFromCGRect
>       NSStringFromCGAffineTransform
>       NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets

Answer (score 0):

Latest syntax:

```
NSLog("%@", NSCoder.string(for: point!))
```