# How to add objects in NSMutableArray with for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitapgesturerecognizer

Here, the issue is nothing but I don't know much about `objectiveC`. So the query is that I am working on a project where user taps on Image and with `UITapGestureRecognizer` I have to store that tapped position in my `array`. I don't know how is this possible that every time user taps the `view` and `CGPoint` value gets stored in `NSMutableArray`.

```
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [getResults count]; i++) {

[dataArray addObject:tappedPoint];
NSLog(@"RESULT TEST %@", dataArray);
}
```

Comment: Anything you have tried to far?

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684463/how-do-i-add-a-cgpoint-to-nsmutablearray) answers your question. You will have to try it yourself.

Comment: [yourArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: point]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass `UIView` and implement the method `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to get a touch callback. Second, a touch location (`CGPoint`) cannot be added to an `NSMutableArray`, but a wrapper class for it can (`NSValue`). Here would be a very basic implementation of what you are going for.

```
// in UIView subclass
// Precondition: you have an NSMutableArray named `someMutableArray'
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    NSValue *wrapper = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchLocation];

    [someMutableArray addObject:wrapper];
}
```

If you want to loop through these touch locations later, all you have to to is fast enumerate through the array and unwrap the `NSValue`s.

```
for (NSValue *wrapper in someMutableArray) {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [wrapper CGPointValue];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian Tracy, you mean that i don't need to implement any for loop,right?

Comment: @SushilSharma No, unless you want to loop through all of the touch locations later.

Comment: Ok,so with this code it will add objects one after another,every time user taps the view.

Comment: Thanks Brian Tracy,thanks a lot for your great solution.